# Adding checkboxes with DataTables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, datatables

i'm using Datatables to make web page which i should use to control a MySQL Table (a really ordinary task). There's one thing that i don't know why it doesn't work. I want to add a column to my table contaninig checkboxes, so later i can use those with some javascript code to do some operations on the rows.
Anyway here's my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Process manager</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/bootstrap/navbar-static-top.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- DataTables bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="css/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <table id="processManager" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>process</th>
                <th>Resource</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Format</th>
                <th>Automaticity</th>
                <th>Process_type</th>
                <th>Access</th>
                <th>Source</th>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>status_A</th>
                <th>status_B</th>
                <th>time_A</th>
                <th>time_B</th>
                <th>exec_A</th>
                <th>exec_B</th>
                <th>period</th>
                <th>overtime</th>
                <th>param</th>
                <th>last_update</th>
                <th>last_triples</th>
                <th>error</th>
                <th>description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>process</th>
                <th>Resource</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Format</th>
                <th>Automaticity</th>
                <th>Process_type</th>
                <th>Access</th>
                <th>Source</th>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>status_A</th>
                <th>status_B</th>
                <th>time_A</th>
                <th>time_B</th>
                <th>exec_A</th>
                <th>exec_B</th>
                <th>period</th>
                <th>overtime</th>
                <th>param</th>
                <th>last_update</th>
                <th>last_triples</th>
                <th>error</th>
                <th>description</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables/jquery-1.10.1.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready( function loadData() {

        processManager = $('#processManager').DataTable( {
            "ajax": {
                url: "getSingleTable.php",
            },
            "columns": [
            {
                "orderable": false,
                // Create an HTML select with all the versions of the data
                //TODO Correggi +01
                "data": function (row, type, val, meta) {
                    return  '<input type="checkbox"/>';
                }
            },
            { "data": "Process ID" },
            { "data": "Resource" },
            { "data": "Category" },
            { "data": "Format" },
            { "data": "Automaticity" },
            { "data": "Process type" },
            { "data": "Access" },
            { "data": "Source" },
            { "data": "A" },
            { "data": "B" },
            { "data": "Status A" },
            { "data": "Status B" },
            { "data": "Time A" },
            { "data": "Time B" },
            { "data": "Exec A" },
            { "data": "Exec B" },
            { "data": "Period" },
            { "data": "Overtime" },
            { "data": "Parameters" },
            { "data": "Last Update" },
            { "data": "Last Triples" },
            { "data": "Error" },
            { "data": "Description" }

            ],
            "language": {
                "decimal": ",",
                "thousands": "."
            },
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
            "order": [[0, 'asc']],
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "stateSave": true
        } );

});

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

getSingleTable.php

```
<?php

// DB table to use
// $table = 'process_manager';
$table = 'process_manager2';

// Table's primary key
// $primaryKey = 'Process';
$primaryKey = 'Process';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array (
        array (
                'db' => 'process',
                'dt' => 'Process ID' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'Resource',
                'dt' => 'Resource' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'Category',
                'dt' => 'Category' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'Format',
                'dt' => 'Format' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'Automaticity',
                'dt' => 'Automaticity' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'Process_type',
                'dt' => 'Process type' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'Access',
                'dt' => 'Access' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'Source',
                'dt' => 'Source' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'A',
                'dt' => 'A' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'B',
                'dt' => 'B' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'status_A',
                'dt' => 'Status A' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'status_B',
                'dt' => 'Status B' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'time_A',
                'dt' => 'Time A' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'time_B',
                'dt' => 'Time B' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'exec_A',
                'dt' => 'Exec A' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'exec_B',
                'dt' => 'Exec B' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'period',
                'dt' => 'Period' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'overtime',
                'dt' => 'Overtime' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'param',
                'dt' => 'Parameters' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'last_update',
                'dt' => 'Last Update' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'last_triples',
                'dt' => 'Last Triples' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'error',
                'dt' => 'Error' 
        ),
        array (
                'db' => 'description',
                'dt' => 'Description' 
        ) 
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array (
        'user' => 'USER',
        'pass' => 'PASS',
        'db' => 'DB',
        'host' => 'IP' 
);

require ('ssp.class.php');

echo json_encode ( SSP::simple ( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns ) );
```

Instead of "USER", "PASS", "DB" and "IP" i put the real values of course.
Everything works fine if i don't try to put the checkboxes.
As you can see i'm trying to put checkboxes in the first column, before "process", wich should be the only column that is not present in the MySQL table.
Anyone know what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the function into `render` parameter not `data` parameter. `data` is for a column name which you don't need there.

```
      "orderable": false,
            // Create an HTML select with all the versions of the data
            //TODO Correggi +01
            "render": function (row, type, val, meta) {
                return  '<input type="checkbox"/>';
        }
```

Comment: Now it get me this error: DataTables warning: table id=processManager - An SQL error occurred: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 10' at line 5

Comment: Well, that's an SQL problem. It has nothing to do with JS. Do you have the SQL code or is it generated somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This is the content of ssp.class.php anyway:

```
<?php

/*
 * Helper functions for building a DataTables server-side processing SQL query
 * The static functions in this class are just helper functions to help build
 *  the SQL used in the DataTables demo server-side processing scripts.
 *  These functions obviously do not represent all that can be done with server-side processing,
 *  they are intentionally simple to show how it works.
 *  More complex server-side processing operations will likely require a custom script.
 *  See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server- side processing requirements of DataTables.
 *  @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
 */

class SSP {

    /**
     * 
     * Create the data output array for the DataTables rows
     *
     * @param array $columns Column information array, with the associations between dataTables and the database
     * @param array $data Data obtained from the SQL SELECT
     * @return array Formatted data in a row based format
     *        
     */
    static function data_output($columns, $data) {

        // Output array
        $out = array ();

        // For each row in data
        for($i = 0, $ien = count ( $data ); $i < $ien; $i ++) {

            // The current row to fulfill (i-th row)
            $row = array ();

            // For each column of the array results-dataTables
            for($j = 0, $jen = count ( $columns ); $j < $jen; $j ++) {

                // The current column
                $column = $columns [$j];

                // If a formatter is set, apply the formatter function
                // The arguments of it are:
                // * id: the column name in database
                // * row: the i-th row of database results
                //
                // The destionation column is identified by 'dt', i.e. the column name in dataTables
                if (isset ( $column['formatter'])) {
                    $row [$column['dt']] = $column['formatter']($data[$i][$column['db']], $data[$i]);
                } 

                // If no formatter is set, set the value of a cell of the current row
                // The destionation column is identified by 'dt', i.e. the column name in dataTables
                // The source cell is in the i-th row of $data, and the column is identified by 'db', i.e. the column name in database
                else {
                    $row [$column['dt']] = $data [$i][$columns [$j]['db']];
                }
            }

            $out [] = $row;
        }

        return $out;
    }


    /**
     *
     * Construct the LIMIT clause for the SQL query
     *
     * @param array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     * @param array $columns Column information array, with the associations between dataTables and the database
     * @return string SQL limit clause to use
     *        
     */
    static function limit($request, $columns) {

        // The limit clause to set
        $limit = '';

        // Set the limit clause, if find the right parameters
        if (isset ( $request ['start'] ) && $request ['length'] != - 1) {
            $limit = "LIMIT " . intval ( $request ['start'] ) . ", " . intval ( $request ['length'] );
        }

        return $limit;
    }


    /**
     *
     * Construct the ORDER BY clause for the SQL query
     *
     * @param array $request Data sent to server by DataTables
     * @param array $columns Column information array, with the associations between dataTables and the database
     * @return string SQL order clause to use
     *        
     */
    static function order($request, $columns) {

        // The order clause to set
        $order = '';

        if (isset ( $request ['order'] ) && count ( $request ['order'] )) {
            $orderBy = array ();
            $dtColumns = self::pluck ( $columns, 'dt' );

            for($i = 0, $ien = count ( $request ['order'] ); $i < $ien; $i ++) {
                // Convert the column index into the column data property
                $columnIdx = intval ( $request ['order'] [$i] ['column'] );
                $requestColumn = $request ['columns'] [$columnIdx];

                $columnIdx = array_search ( $requestColumn ['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns [$columnIdx];

                if ($requestColumn ['orderable'] == 'true') {
                    $dir = $request ['order'] [$i] ['dir'] === 'asc' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';

                    $orderBy [] = '`' . $column ['db'] . '` ' . $dir;
                }
            }

            $order = 'ORDER BY ' . implode ( ', ', $orderBy );
        }

        return $order;
    }

    /**
     * Searching / Filtering
     *
     * Construct the WHERE clause for server-side processing SQL query.
     *
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here performance on large
     * databases would be very poor
     *
     * @param array $request
     *          Data sent to server by DataTables
     * @param array $columns
     *          Column information array
     * @param array $bindings
     *          Array of values for PDO bindings, used in the
     *          sql_exec() function
     * @return string SQL where clause
     *        
     */
    static function filter($request, $columns, &$bindings) {
        $globalSearch = array ();
        $columnSearch = array ();
        $dtColumns = self::pluck ( $columns, 'dt' );

        if (isset ( $request ['search'] ) && $request ['search'] ['value'] != '') {
            $str = $request ['search'] ['value'];

            for($i = 0, $ien = count ( $request ['columns'] ); $i < $ien; $i ++) {
                $requestColumn = $request ['columns'] [$i];
                $columnIdx = array_search ( $requestColumn ['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns [$columnIdx];

                if ($requestColumn ['searchable'] == 'true') {
                    $binding = self::bind ( $bindings, '%' . $str . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                    $globalSearch [] = "`" . $column ['db'] . "` LIKE " . $binding;
                }
            }
        }

        // Individual column filtering
        for($i = 0, $ien = count ( $request ['columns'] ); $i < $ien; $i ++) {
            $requestColumn = $request ['columns'] [$i];
            $columnIdx = array_search ( $requestColumn ['data'], $dtColumns );
            $column = $columns [$columnIdx];

            $str = $requestColumn ['search'] ['value'];

            if ($requestColumn ['searchable'] == 'true' && $str != '') {
                $binding = self::bind ( $bindings, '%' . $str . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $columnSearch [] = "`" . $column ['db'] . "` LIKE " . $binding;
            }
        }

        // Combine the filters into a single string
        $where = '';

        if (count ( $globalSearch )) {
            $where = '(' . implode ( ' OR ', $globalSearch ) . ')';
        }

        if (count ( $columnSearch )) {
            $where = $where === '' ? implode ( ' AND ', $columnSearch ) : $where . ' AND ' . implode ( ' AND ', $columnSearch );
        }

        if ($where !== '') {
            $where = 'WHERE ' . $where;
        }

        return $where;
    }

    /**
     * Perform the SQL queries needed for an server-side processing requested,
     * utilising the helper functions of this class, limit(), order() and
     * filter() among others.
     * The returned array is ready to be encoded as JSON
     * in response to an SSP request, or can be modified if needed before
     * sending back to the client.
     *
     * @param array $request
     *          Data sent to server by DataTables
     * @param array $sql_details
     *          SQL connection details - see sql_connect()
     * @param string $table
     *          SQL table to query
     * @param string $primaryKey
     *          Primary key of the table
     * @param array $columns
     *          Column information array
     * @return array Server-side processing response array
     *        
     */
    static function simple($request, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns) {

        //TODO Non chiara l'utilità di bindings
        $bindings = array ();

        // Get an handle to the database connection
        $db = self::sql_connect ( $sql_details );

        // Build the SQL query string from the request
        $limit = self::limit ( $request, $columns );
        $order = self::order ( $request, $columns );
        $where = self::filter ( $request, $columns, $bindings );

        // The query to get the data
        $data = self::sql_exec ( $db, $bindings, "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `" . implode ( "`, `", self::pluck ( $columns, 'db' ) ) . "`
            FROM `$table`
            $where
            $order
            $limit" );

        // Dataset length after filtering
        $resFilterLength = self::sql_exec ( $db, "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()" );
        $recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0];

        // Total data set length
        $resTotalLength = self::sql_exec ( $db, "SELECT COUNT(`{$primaryKey}`) FROM `$table`" );
        $recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0];

        // Data output
        return array (
                "draw" => intval ($request['draw']),
                "recordsTotal" => intval ($recordsTotal),
                "recordsFiltered" => intval ($recordsFiltered),
                "data" => self::data_output ($columns, $data) 
        );
    }


    /**
     * 
     * Connect to the specified database, returning an handle to it.
     *
     * @param array $sql_details
     *          SQL server connection details array, with the
     *          properties:
     *          * host - host name
     *          * db - database name
     *          * user - user name
     *          * pass - user password
     * @return resource Database connection handle
     *        
     */
    static function sql_connect($sql_details) {

        // Try to connect to the specified database
        try {
            $db = @new PDO (
                "mysql:host={$sql_details['host']};dbname={$sql_details['db']}",
                $sql_details ['user'],
                $sql_details ['pass'],
                array (
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8", 
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET CHARACTER SET utf8" 
                )
            );
        } 
        // Catch an exception if it was not possible to connect to database
        catch ( PDOException $e ) {
            self::fatal ("An error occurred while connecting to the database. " . "The error reported by the server was: " . $e->getMessage () );
        }

        return $db;
    }

    /**
     * Execute an SQL query on the database
     *
     * @param resource $db
     *          Database handler
     * @param array $bindings
     *          Array of PDO binding values from bind() to be
     *          used for safely escaping strings. Note that this can be given as the
     *          SQL query string if no bindings are required.
     * @param string $sql
     *          SQL query to execute.
     * @return array Result from the query (all rows)
     *        
     */
    static function sql_exec($db, $bindings, $sql = null) {
        // Argument shifting
        // NON MI PIACE
        if ($sql === null) {
            $sql = $bindings;
        }

        // Prepare the statement for execution
        $stmt = $db->prepare ( $sql );

        // Bind parameters
        //TODO Capire questo blocco
        if (is_array ( $bindings )) {
            for($i = 0, $ien = count ( $bindings ); $i < $ien; $i ++) {
                $binding = $bindings [$i];
                $stmt->bindValue ( $binding ['key'], $binding ['val'], $binding ['type'] );
            }
        }

        // Try to execute the statement
        try {
            $stmt->execute();
        } 
        // Catch an exception
        catch ( PDOException $e ) {
            self::fatal ( "An SQL error occurred: " . $e->getMessage () );
        }

        // Return all the result sets rows
        return $stmt->fetchAll ();
    }


    /**
     * 
     * Throw a fatal error.
     *
     * This writes out an error message in a JSON string which DataTables will
     * see and show to the user in the browser.
     *
     * @param string $msg Message to send to the client
     *          
     */
    static function fatal($msg) {
        echo json_encode (
            array ("error" => $msg)
        );

        exit (0);
    }


    /**
     * Create a PDO binding key which can be used for escaping variables safely
     * when executing a query with sql_exec()
     *
     * @param
     *          array &$a Array of bindings
     * @param * $val
     *          Value to bind
     * @param int $type
     *          PDO field type
     * @return string Bound key to be used in the SQL where this parameter
     *         would be used.
     *        
     */
    static function bind(&$a, $val, $type) {
        $key = ':binding_' . count ( $a );

        $a [] = array (
                'key' => $key,
                'val' => $val,
                'type' => $type 
        );

        return $key;
    }


    /**
     * Pull a particular property from each associative
     * array in a numeric array,
     * returning an array of the property values from each item.
     *
     * @param array $a Array to get data from
     * @param string $prop Property to read
     * @return array Array of property values
     *        
     */
    static function pluck($a, $prop) {
        $out = array ();

        for ($i=0, $len=count($a); $i<$len; $i ++) {
            $out[] = $a[$i][$prop];
        }

        return $out;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.
I faced the same problem and the keyword of solution is **render** as some already pointed.

here is a share of fully working example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Custom datatable work</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "your_server_feed.php",
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": 5,  // column target which that render will return text to, starts from 0 
                "data": "text",
                "render": function(data, type, full, meta) { /
                    return 'Put here any html or text, your case <input type="checkbox">';
                }
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
<table id="example" cellspacing="0" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>column 5</th><!-- this is the column where you want to add a checkbox, image or icon...etc -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Column 5</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

For further reading kindly go to :
[Datatable Column Render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)